# Export podcast subscriptions from iOS podcast app as OPML

Tags: podcasts.app

I want to EXPORT my podcast subscriptions from the iPhone/iPad Podcast app into another podcatcher. In order to be able to import I need an OPML-file with the subscriptions.

Can I create such a file or is there another way to get the subscriptions exported?

Answer (score 7):

I've been looking for a way to do this, but can't find a way to do it directly. Here's a workaround.

If you sync with iTunes, then you can export the OPML files from iTunes:

In iTunes 11, open Podcasts and then choose File > Library > Export playlist, then select OPML format.

Or, right-click on the Podcasts entry in the side bar (if the sidebar is not showing, click View > Show Sidebar, select "Export...", then select OPML format.

Answer (score 4):

This is really a comment to the above answer, but is too long for stackexchange.

I got @nthonygreen's answer to work, but it was surprisingly not-obvious how to do it.

The first mistake I made was: I had my iPhone connected to my computer, and iTunes was displaying the phone's stuff in the left panel; the FIle > Library > Export menu was greyed out.  It took me a long time to realize that I needed to click an icon in the upper-left that showed me podcasts in general, as opposed to podcasts on the phone; *then* I could export.

Then importing was tricky!  I wound up emailing the opml file to myself, and clicking the attachment in the mail app ... this displayed the raw XML full-screen, with no obvious way to do anything with it (like get Overcast to import it, which is what I ultimately wanted).  Eventually I noticed that if I tapped on the screen, a menu bar appeared at the top of the screen, and it had an "export" icon (a square with an arrow pointing up from its center); tapping that showed me a bunch of icons, and I was able to scroll them to reveal Overcast ... which happily imported it.  Phew!

Comment: Answers shouldn't be used for comments.  This should be posted as another answer or as an edit to the original answer.

Comment: Assuming you use iCloud Drive, just export to iCloud Drive on your Mac and it's then easy to *Copy to Overcast* (in "export"/share menu) in iOS iCloud Drive app