# Exporting podcasts from iOS app as OPML

Tags: podcasts

I have finally decided to switch from the Apple Podcast app to Overcast, but I cannot find a way to move my subscriptions. A ([similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97254/export-podcast-subscriptions-from-ios-podcast-app-as-opml)) was asked a while ago, but iTunes has changed since then, and the new MacOS app doesn't have those menus. So, I was wondering if anyone knows another way to get an OPML file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Podcasts app appears to store its data inside a sqlite database. Using the information inside we can create an OPML file that Overcast (or any good podcast app) will accept.

Here's a script that I made that will create the OPML file:

```
#!/bin/bash

sql() {
    sqlite3 "${HOME}/Library/Group Containers/"*.groups.com.apple.podcasts/Documents/MTLibrary.sqlite "select ${1} from ZMTPODCAST ${2:+"where ${2} = '${3}'"};" |\
        sed -e 's/&/\&amp;/g' \
            -e 's/</\&lt;/g' \
            -e 's/>/\&lgt;/g' \
            -e "s/'/\&apos;/g"
}

opml_export=${HOME}/Desktop/podcasts.opml
cat > ${opml_export} << HEAD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<opml version="1.0">
  <head><title>Podcast Subscriptions</title></head>
  <body>
    <outline text="feeds">
HEAD

sql ZUUID | while read -r uuid ; do
    feed_url=$(sql ZFEEDURL ZUUID "${uuid}")
    home_url=$(sql ZWEBPAGEURL ZUUID "${uuid}")
    title=$(sql ZTITLE ZUUID "${uuid}")
    cat <<EOT
<outline type="rss" text="${title}" title="${title}" xmlUrl="${feed_url}" htmlUrl="${home_url}" />
EOT
done >> ${opml_export}

cat >> ${opml_export} << TAIL
    </outline>
  </body>
</opml>
TAIL
```

For people unfamiliar with how to run scripts on the command line, it's easy:

- copy the entire text from the gray box above
- open the Terminal app
- at your Terminal prompt, type:

  - `pbpaste > export_podcasts.sh`, pasting the text into an appropriately named file
  - hit `return`, then type:
  - `chmod u+x export_podcasts.sh`, making your file executable
  - hit `return`, then type:
  - `./export_podcasts.sh`, executing your script

This will create `podcasts.opml` on your desktop.

To get this file to your iPhone, you can use AirDrop or iCloud Drive:

*AirDrop* - Make sure your Mac and iPhone have AirDrop enabled, you can right click on the file, then `Share > AirDrop`, and tap the icon showing your iPhone's avatar and phone name. This should automatically open the file on your iPhone and allow you to start the import in Overcast.

*iCloud Drive* - If iCloud Drive is set up on your Mac and iPhone, you can move `podcasts.opml` into an iCloud Drive folder on your Mac, and then open the file from your Files app on iPhone. It should then prompt you to "Open with Overcast", which should then import the podcasts in the file.

Comment: awesome, it worked like a charm! and sorry for a late response, I have completely forgotten about this question lol

Comment: This works just fine, although it seems that Overcast doesn't import the private feeds (which are present in the OPML file).

Comment: Overcast opened my OPML file and said the import was successful, but no podcasts were added to my library. I have a relatively large library of podcasts, and a lot of private RSS feeds. Maybe there's a bug in Overcast (v. 2021.5)?

Comment: How does this script compare to this Podcast exporter tool? https://liujiacai.net/podcasts-opml-exporter/

Comment: Can confirm they export the same XML list of podcast RSS feeds. Minor inconsequential diff: this script includes `title` attribute in addition to the `text` attribute with the same content, and also a `htmlUrl` attribute in addition to the `xmlUrl`, which sometimes are different from one another, but the mentioned tool with `xmlUrl´ only seemed to work fine. So try one you'd like, and if not try the other approach.